# Node Express requiring token despite whitelist, and only when request coming from Stripe

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments, webhooks, express-jwt

I have an endpoint `.../webhook/stripe` for Stripe to POST event data to. However when Stripe sends and event, it returns a "Not authorized" error that I expect when trying to access a secure endpoint.

I have whitelisted the endpoint in the expressJWT middleware. When I call the same endpoint from my Postman without a token, it accepts the call (but errors from Stripe signature, fair enough!)

Why would express expect a token from one remote but not another?

**constants.js**

```js
...
    ,
    UNSECURED_ROUTES: {
        path: [
            { url: '/api/v1/', methods: [ 'GET', ], },
            { url: '/api/v1/callback', methods: [ 'GET', 'POST', ], },
            { url: /^\/api\/v1\/callback(.*)/, methods: [ 'GET', 'POST', ], },
            { url: '/api/v1/webhook', methods: [ 'GET', 'POST', ], },
            { url: /^\/api\/v1\/webhook\/.*/, methods: [ 'GET', 'POST', ], },
        ],
    },
```

**app.js**

```js
app.use(jwtCheck.unless(UNSECURED_ROUTES));
app.use('/api/v1', apiRoutesv1);
```

**index.js**

```js
router.post('/webhook/:service', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        switch (req.params.service) {
            case 'stripe':
            default:
                await accountService.receiveWebhook({ payload: req.body, signature: req.headers[ 'stripe-signature' ], });
                // acknowledge receipt
                return res.status(200);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

API response to Stripe:

```js
{
  "success": false,
  "error": {
    "code": "credentials_required",
    "message": "No authorization token was found"
  }
}
```

Error logs when Stripe sends webhook event:

```
2022-07-05T22:17:52.743919736Z 6/07/2022, 10:17:52 am [ ERROR | UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found
```

Error logs when I send request from Postman without an auth token set

```
2022-07-05T22:18:27.909325736Z 6/07/2022, 10:18:27 am [ ERROR |     No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing ]
```

Comment: Do you have any logging on your end to check the exact raw URL each request is hitting? If you don't have it already, can you add it? It feels like Stripe and your Postman request may be hitting subtly different URLs resulting in the different behavior

Comment: Yea I do, I tried to include more logs in the OP but the automated spam-bot wouldn't let me...

From Postman:
`"x-original-url":"/api/v1/webhook/stripe"`

From Stripe:
`"x-original-url":"/api/v1/webook/stripe"`

And would you look at that...couldn't spot the missing "h" in Stripe for hours until you pointed it out!

Answer (score 0):

Stripe webhook had subtle spelling mistake in the endpoint.

`/api/v1/webook/stripe`

should be

`/api/v1/webhook/stripe`

Thanks goes to [karbi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14107360/karbi)